# General Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

New to C++ and I have a general linked list question.  Say I have:

```
struct Node 
{
    string name;
    Node *next
};
```

in a header file and I have a function

```
Node ReadIntoList(const string INPUT_FILE)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    Node *perPtr;
    perPtr = new Node;

    inFile.open(INPUT_FILE);
    while(inFile && perPtr!= NULL)
    {
        getline(inFile, perPtr->name);
        perPtr -> next = head;
        head = perPtr;
        perPtr = new Node;
    }
    delete perPtr;
    perPtr = NULL;

    return *head;
}
```

My question is what do I need to return from the ReadIntoList function to main
so that I can access the list and then be able to setup a function to output it
to a file.  Here is my main so far...

```
int main()
{
    ofstream oFile;
    string inputFile;
    Node *head;

    cout << left;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file you would like to "
            "use: ";

    getline(cin, inputFile);

    head = ReadIntoList(inputFile);

    oFile.open("OFile.txt");


    return 0;
}
```

This Node in main is not setup properly obviously but I'm not sure how to access the info from ReadIntoList.

Comment: If you are really using C++ then you should be using `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead of managing nodes manually.

Comment: 1. See @RemyLebeau answer above.
2. If for any reason (e.g., you wish to implement your own), you may simply return `head` in `ReadIntoList`, and you can set `head` in your main from the return value of `ReadIntoList`

Comment: to answer your specific question,general for a simple list you can treat the head pointer as the handle to the list. so thats what you should return. But you dont show what you return in the question (the code is cut off). Those delete perPtr calls look very odd. Use std::list as other have said

Comment: I apologize for cutting off the code, I have it setup to return *head;

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps: in the original code, it cannot "simply return `head`" because the loop assigns `head` on each iteration, so `head` points at the **last** node allocated, not the **first** node.

Comment: @pm100 They're there because the while loop will always generate an extra node on its final iteration that isn't needed.

Comment: Unless your code is inside a class, you should move it from a header file into a source file (usually `.cpp`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- AFAIR, when I posted, the definition of `ReadIntoList` was not complete and it almost seemed like pseudo-code like C sketching out the implementation.  Now that there is an implementation -- You are right.  `head` is simply a poorly named variable in `ReadIntoList`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `ReadIntoList()` is returning the **content** of the **last** node in the list (which will crash if the input file fails to open).  `ReadIntoList()` needs to instead return **a pointer** to the **first** node in the list.  That will allow `main()` to loop through the list, eg:

```
Node* ReadIntoList(const string &inputFile)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    Node *perPtr = NULL;

    inFile.open(inputFile);
    if (inFile)
    {
        do
        {
            perPtr = new Node;
            if (!getline(inFile, perPtr->name))
            {
                delete perPtr;
                break;
            }
            perPtr->next = NULL;

            if (!head) head = perPtr;
            if (last) last->next = perPtr;
            last = perPtr;
        }
        while (true);
    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream oFile;
    string inputFile;
    Node *head;
    Node *perPtr;
    Node *tmp;

    cout << left;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file you would like to use: ";

    getline(cin, inputFile);

    head = ReadIntoList(inputFile);
    if (head)
    {    
        oFile.open("OFile.txt");
        if (oFile)
        {
            perPtr = head;
            do
            {
                oFile << perPtr->name << endl;
                perPtr = perPtr->next;
            }
            while (perPtr != NULL);
        }

        perPtr = head;
        do
        {
            tmp = perPtr->next;
            delete perPtr;
            perPtr = tmp;
        }
        while (perPtr != NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, since you are using C++, you should be using `std::list` (or `std::forward_list` in C++11 and later) instead, eg:

```
#include <list>

bool ReadIntoList(const string &inputFile, list<string> &outList)
{
    outList.clear();

    ifstream inFile(inputFile);
    if (!inFile)
        return false;

    string name;
    while (getline(inFile, name))
        outList.push_back(name);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream oFile;
    string inputFile;
    list<string> items;

    cout << left;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file you would like to use: ";

    getline(cin, inputFile);

    if (ReadIntoList(inputFile, items))
    {
        oFile.open("OFile.txt");
        if (oFile)
        {
            for (list<string>::const_iterator iter = items.begin(), end = items.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
            {
                oFile << *iter << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```